# How to share same nodejs port (3000) with multiple vhost (also nodejs app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Relating to vhost for multiple domain apps on node server, I'm now facing an issue of not able to call app.js of vhost domain.

My setup is like following:

```
root folder : website
vhost folder: website/vietvan
vhost folder: website/thanksme
```

The root app.js on root website is as follows:

```
var vhost = require('vhost');
// Module dependencies.
var application_root = __dirname,
    express = require( 'express' ),
    vhost = require( 'vhost' );

function createVirtualHost(domainName, dirPath) {
    return vhost(domainName, express.static( dirPath ));
}

//Create server
var app = express();

//Create the virtual hosts
var vietvanVhost = createVirtualHost("vietvan.net","./vietvan/");

var thanksmeVhost = createVirtualHost("leean.me","./thanksme/");
//Use the virtual hosts

app.use(thanksmeVhost);
app.use(vietvanVhost);

//Start server
var port = 3000;
app.listen( port, function() {
    console.log( 'Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env );
});
```

---

On vietvan folder the app.js as follows:

```
let postRoutes = require('./routes/post');
let userRoutes = require('./routes/users');
let commentRoutes = require('./routes/comment');
let appRoutes = require('./routes/app');

let app = express();
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/thanksme');
console.log('connected to DB');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/post', postRoutes);
app.use('/comment', commentRoutes);
app.use('/', appRoutes);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  return res.render('index');
});
//
// app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000 of vietvan.net');

// });
```

---

When start the node pointing to root app.js
I can not get access to the vhost `http://vietvan.net:3000`, the error:

> cannot GET /

But if I start the node point to `/websites/vietvan/app.js` or change the `vietvanVhost = createVirtualHost("vietvan.net","./vietvan/");` to the `/vietvan/dist` in the `createVirtualHost()` then it's OK and start serving the compiled code in dist folder of vietvan folder.

Seems that the app.js in the vietvan folder didn't work, or did not get called by the root app.js then cause of issue.

Can anybody help to point out where I made a mistake? And how to fix the issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: vhost expects second parameter to be handler, you are passing the content of a file or something like that...

Comment: can you make more clear please ? i passed second param to the vhost as folder of target vhost , is that the var vietvanVhost = createVirtualHost("vietvan.net","./vietvan/"); ??? , if not so what is the correct usage ? thank you